# UPS gives power without being switched on

Tags: ups

I am using Intex Protector 275 UPS. When I connect it to power source, it automatically gives power to its output devices without switching on the UPS. This problem started today and I'm not able to figure out why is it happening. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Most power buttons today just complete a low voltage sensor. It could have been ON before you unplugged it and plugged it back in (retaining its state). Get it operating normally, leave it plugged in, turn it OFF, unplug it and then try again plugging it in. Does it turn itself ON again?

Comment: I guess there is an internal problem with the UPS. It started to function normally after two days but again gave this problem after a week.  PS. Sorry for late response. Actually my PC's WiFi also stopped working that day after posting this question. I'm not even able to buy a replacement adapter due to lockdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some UPSes have bypass sockets which get power as long as the UPS is plugged on.

Other sockets will be connected to the battery and managed by the UPS power button.

It's also possible your UPS has a feature that if the battery is dead or disconnected, all power sockets are bypassed to wall power, so at least devices are useable.

You should consult the manual for this UPS if you still have it (I was not able to find one).